# error ‘underlying_type_t’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a template type in example.cpp from project-OSRM

Tags: c++11, osrm

I try to execute the [examle.cpp](https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/tree/master/example) file of Project-OSRM. I did the following steps:

- build OSRM from source as described [here](https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend)
- in new terminal: cd osrm-backend/example
- in the terminal: cmake ..
- in the terminal: cmake --build .
- in the terminal: sudo cmake --build . --target install
- move the maps *contractor*, *engine*, *extractor*, *partition*, *storage*, *util* from */usr/local/include/osrm* to */usr/local/include* (else error maps are not in /usr/local/include)
- in the terminal: g++ -std=c++11 example.cpp -o example

But I get the error

```
‘underlying_type_t’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a template type
     static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<RouteParameters::AnnotationsType>>
```

Does anyone have a idea what I'm doing wrong or what is going wrong and how to solve this?

**Error message**

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/engine/api/match_parameters.hpp:31:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/osrm/match_parameters.hpp:31,
                 from example.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/engine/api/route_parameters.hpp: In function ‘bool osrm::engine::api::operator&(osrm::engine::api::RouteParameters::AnnotationsType, osrm::engine::api::RouteParameters::AnnotationsType)’:
/usr/local/include/engine/api/route_parameters.hpp:144:26: error: ‘underlying_type_t’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a template type
         static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<RouteParameters::AnnotationsType>>(l
                          ^
/usr/local/include/engine/api/route_parameters.hpp:144:43: error: expected ‘>’ before ‘<’ token
         static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<RouteParameters::AnnotationsType>>(l
                                           ^
/usr/local/include/engine/api/route_parameters.hpp:144:43: error: expected ‘(’ before ‘<’ token
/usr/local/include/engine/api/route_parameters.hpp:144:43: error: expected primary-expression before ‘<’ token
/usr/local/include/engine/api/route_parameters.hpp:144:76: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>>’ token
    static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<RouteParameters::AnnotationsType>>(lhs) &
                                                                       ^
/usr/local/include/engine/api/route_parameters.hpp:145:26: error: ‘underlying_type_t’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a template type
         static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<RouteParameters::AnnotationsType>>(r
                          ^
/usr/local/include/engine/api/route_parameters.hpp:145:43: error: expected ‘>’ before ‘<’ token
         static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<RouteParameters::AnnotationsType>>(r
                                           ^
/usr/local/include/engine/api/route_parameters.hpp:145:43: error: expected ‘(’ before ‘<’ token
/usr/local/include/engine/api/route_parameters.hpp:145:43: error: expected primary-expression before ‘<’ token
/usr/local/include/engine/api/route_parameters.hpp:145:76: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>>’ token
    static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<RouteParameters::AnnotationsType>>(rhs));
                                                                       ^
/usr/local/include/engine/api/route_parameters.hpp:145:84: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token
    static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<RouteParameters::AnnotationsType>>(rhs));
                                                                               ^
/usr/local/include/engine/api/route_parameters.hpp:145:84: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token
/usr/local/include/engine/api/route_parameters.hpp: In function ‘osrm::engine::api::RouteParameters::AnnotationsType osrm::engine::api::operator|(osrm::engine::api::RouteParameters::AnnotationsType, osrm::engine::api::RouteParameters::AnnotationsType)’:
/usr/local/include/engine/api/route_parameters.hpp:152:26: error: ‘underlying_type_t’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a template type
         static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<RouteParameters::AnnotationsType>>(l
                          ^
/usr/local/include/engine/api/route_parameters.hpp:152:43: error: expected ‘>’ before ‘<’ token
         static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<RouteParameters::AnnotationsType>>(l
                                           ^
/usr/local/include/engine/api/route_parameters.hpp:152:43: error: expected ‘(’ before ‘<’ token
/usr/local/include/engine/api/route_parameters.hpp:152:43: error: expected primary-expression before ‘<’ token
/usr/local/include/engine/api/route_parameters.hpp:152:76: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>>’ token
    static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<RouteParameters::AnnotationsType>>(lhs) |
                                                                       ^
/usr/local/include/engine/api/route_parameters.hpp:153:26: error: ‘underlying_type_t’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a template type
         static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<RouteParameters::AnnotationsType>>(r
                          ^
/usr/local/include/engine/api/route_parameters.hpp:153:43: error: expected ‘>’ before ‘<’ token
         static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<RouteParameters::AnnotationsType>>(r
                                           ^
/usr/local/include/engine/api/route_parameters.hpp:153:43: error: expected ‘(’ before ‘<’ token
/usr/local/include/engine/api/route_parameters.hpp:153:43: error: expected primary-expression before ‘<’ token
/usr/local/include/engine/api/route_parameters.hpp:153:76: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>>’ token
    static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<RouteParameters::AnnotationsType>>(rhs));
                                                                       ^
/usr/local/include/engine/api/route_parameters.hpp:153:84: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token
    static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<RouteParameters::AnnotationsType>>(rhs));
                                                                               ^
/usr/local/include/engine/api/route_parameters.hpp:153:84: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token
```

Comment: `underlying_type_t` requires c++14 like most of the `*_t` aliases.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`underlying_type_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/underlying_type) requires C++14. To be able to use it pass `-std=c++14` to your compiler.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to

```
#include <type_traits>
```

This missing directive also lead to the same (confusing) error message.